# Correct stability order of resonance structures

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, resonance

Question no 9 as far as I know none of the rules of relative order of stability apply to this( completion of octate,charge seperation etc.) So they all must be equally stable but the answer is (D)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compound II and III have 2 aromatic rings whereas I and IV have only 1 aromatic ring, and more the number of aromatic rings, the more the compound is stable.

> Aromatic molecules are very stable, and do not break apart easily to
>   react with other substances. Organic compounds that are not aromatic
>   are classified as aliphatic compounds—they might be cyclic, but only
>   aromatic rings have special stability (low reactivity).

Thus stability of II= stability of III and stability of I = stability of IV.

And since II and III have greater number of aromatic rings than I and IV,

Stability(II,III) > Stability(I,IV)

Thus the answer would be [**Option D**] and not [**Option C**].